# Error when running ifup -a

Tags: networking, ip-address

Last week I tried to change the IP address of my Linux computer to static:

```
address 192.168.10.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
gateway 192.168.10.1
```

Then I tried to run `ifup -a` and I got this error:

```
ip:either "local" is duplicate, or "/24" is garbage  
ip: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Can anybody tell me what this means and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The second error usually means that the interface is already configured and "up" and therefore an error is issued.

Executing first "ifdown -a" (or "ifdown ethX" for just one specific interface) should solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an `lxc` container with an identical interface `stanza`:

```
ip: either "local" is duplicate, or "/24" is garbage
ip: RTNETLINK answers: Network unreachable
```

The solution was to remove & paste the settings into `/etc/network/interfaces` again & make sure there was a carriage return after the `gateway` entry (i.e press `<enter>` after the last line in the `stanza`).

In my case this was probably caused by whitespace in the file. I normally set `#!/bin/sh` at the top of `/etc/network/interfaces` so when I edit it with `nano` whitespace shows up as green (for this to work with `lxc` containers you would need to connect via `ssh` rather than `lxc-console`).